# Remove first columns delimiter

Tags: awk, sed

I have a CSV file with `;` delimiter:

```
3;85;2;8;9;5;8;6
7;4;5;6;2;2;4;6
```

I would like to have this output:

```
38528;9;5;8;6
7456;2;2;4;6
```

In general, I am trying to remove the delimiter from the three first columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<4;i++)sub(/;/,"")}1' file
38528;9;5;8;6
7456;2;2;4;6
```

Answer (score 3):

**awk approach**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $1$2$3$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' input_file
38528;9;5;8;6
7456;2;2;4;6
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed 's/;//;s/;//;s/;//' file
```

*(replace `;` with nothing, 3 times)*

Answer (score 1):

In sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);/\1\2\3/' infile
38528;9;5;8;6
7456;2;2;4;6
```

This looks for and captures the pattern "a sequence of non-semicolons" followed by a semicolon, three times, and substitutes by the captured sequences not containing the semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

hacky version of removing first three column delimiters:

```
sed -f <(echo "s/;//;"{,,}) file
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sed 's/;//1;s/;//1;s/;//1'   Input_file
```

substitute semi colon on first position, then do the same operation 2 more times because one it will be done for example first position then second occurrence will become first semi colon then.